# Access polymorphic attribute in the view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, paperclip

Trying to work out this small issue, I have finally got my polymorphic association working but now cant seem to figure out how to show an image in the view once a record has been saved.

My setup

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

attr_accessible :photo
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small_blog => "250x250#", :large_blog => "680x224#", :thumb => "95x95#" }
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :images, as: :imageable

accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
attr_accessible :comments, :title, :images_attributes

end
```

So in my view i have this at the moment, which is throwing undefined method 'photo' error

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
<%= image_tag(p.photo.url(:large_blog), :class => 'image') %>
<% end %>
```

Any pointers appreciated

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but you a calling photo on a post, but  according to models post has many images, and each image has a photo, not a post.

Comment: how would you approach this? maybe this is why im getting mixed up? appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post has many images, and each image has a photo. So it can go like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %> 
  <% p.images.each do |i| %>
    <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:large_blog), :class => 'image') %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ah i see, yeah that makes sense now..thank you for clearing that up, always get mixed up when dealing with nested attributes in the views.. so with this a post has many images, so we follow the path through the block, post -> images -> attribute